# Backslash Problem when Running Script for Windows Scheduler (via a batch file)

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, xlsxwriter

So, up until about a year ago I had several scripts that I ran via Windows Task Scheduler then all of a sudden I started getting 0x1 "errors".

Fast forward to present and I decided to try to figure out what was going on (because I really need some stuff to run when I am away).  I have one python script that imports several others to run.  Based on numerous other posts about problems with Task Scheduler,: I decided to use a .bat file

```
SET logfile="C:\Reports\batch.log"
@echo off
@echo Starting Script at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
call C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat activate C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3
C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\Me\RUN_daily_notifications.py
pause
@echo finished at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
```

In many of the scripts that are executed are paths to different files here and there and the command line execution crashes at the first one (so I would assume I would need to fix them all).  For example, in the first script I am setting up an Excel file:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'P:\1MatData\Query Output\Hold Report.xlsx')
```

I run this via the Task Scheduler, the command line opens up and gives me this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET logfile="C:\Reports\batch.log"
Running Eng_Que
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\RUN_daily_notifications.py", line 13, in <module>
    import Eng_Que  #G8
  File "C:\Users\Me\Eng_Que.py", line 140, in <module>
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'P:\1MatData\Query Output\Hold Report.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlsxwriter.py", line 182, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 810, in __init__
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 651, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P:\\1MatData\\Query Output\\Hold Report.xlsx'
```

I've tried rewriting the line with the path in the script numerous ways, but never can seen to get a single backslash to pass.

For example (changes to the script and command line error):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('P:\\1MatData\\Query Output\\Hold Report.xlsx')
```

still passes double backslashes:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P:\\1MatData\\Query Output\\Hold Report.xlsx'
```

This:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('P:\1MatData\Query Output\Hold Report.xlsx')
```

Gives:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P:\x01MatData\\Query Output\\Hold Report.xlsx'
```

All of these (except for the last one of course) work fine in my terminal (Sy
pder).
I've also tried os.path.normpath and .realpath and still can't get single backslashes.  Any advice, wisdom or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit to provide additional info requested:

The P: drive is a network drive that I have read/write access to.

Task properties:

General--
Selected Run only when user is logged on and have Run with highest privileges checked.

Actions--
Program/script:  C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BatchFiles\daily_reports.bat
Add arguments:  blank
Start in:  blank

Settings--
Allow task to be run on demand -- checked
Stop the task if it runs longer than:  3 days
If the running task does not end when requested force it to stop -- checked.

Comment: If you ever have problems with backslashes in a path, it is always worthwhile to try just using forward slashes. With that said, I'm not sure that's the problem here.

Comment: I tried 'writer = pd.ExcelWriter("P:/1MatData/Solumina Query Output/Engineering Hold Report.xlsx")' which gave me:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P:/1MatData/Solumina Query Output/Engineering Hold Report.xlsx'

Comment: Is `P:` a network / mapped drive which is available at the time your Scheduled Task is being run? and for which the user under whose context the task is being run has the required privileges? In order to diagnose issues with Scheduled Tasks, you should provide all of the configuration details of that task. Please [edit] your question to include them; thank you. Also as a side note, there is no such command as `@echo`, it is just `echo`. _(The `@` is a special character which turns off echoing of the command which follows it)._

Comment: Ok, added the Task configuration info.  Yes the P: drive is a network drive and I have read/write access to the 1MatData folder.